# How do i see output from "asp.net core web server" if debugging in Docker container with Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core

I am developing an app with ASP.NET Core 2.1 in Visual Studio 2017. I am using Visual Studio's Docker support so the project runs inside of a Docker container.

I am currently debugging a with the debug arrow labeled "Docker" at the top of the screen.

However, I do not get the "ASP.NET Core Web Server" option in the Output window's "Show output from:" drop down box.

How do I see my Docker containerized project's debugging output for its "asp.net core web server"?

Comment: I used logger factory and logged all output to a readable location. Maybe that will help

Comment: What do you want to check from `asp.net core web server`? After running from `docker`, it will output logs in the `Debug` tab.